# Async WebRequest freezes application

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am building an app that will have registration option and I've made a method for checking whether username is available or not that is async. Method connects via WebRequest to my PHP/MySQL API and retrieves if username is taken or not.

However whenever I try to run this the code blocks on line

```
var response = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

and whole application just freezes. Doing this same method synchronously works fine though.

Whole method:

```
async public Task<UsernameAvailable> usernameAvailable()
{
    try
    {
        token = "token=single";
        function = "&function=checkUser";
        string param = "&param=" + User.username;

        string result = "";

        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://" + APIURL + token + function + param);
        var response = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync(); //troubled line
        var content = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(content);

        result = reader.ReadLine();

        if (result == "0")
        {
            state = "Username is available.";
            return UsernameAvailable.Available;
        }
        else
        {
            state = "Username is not available.";
            return UsernameAvailable.NotAvailable;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        state = "Error checking for username.";
        return UsernameAvailable.Error;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Synced* isn't the same as *synchronously*

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer It's in the context. I've updated the question.

Comment: How are you calling `usernameAvailable`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov switch(API.UsernameAvailable().Result) (it's a method for my API class connection). Your answer did the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to go on a wild guess here and say that higher up the callstack you're calling `usernameAvailable` like this:

```
usernameAvailable().Result
```

Which is blocking on async code, causing your app to deadlock. [*This is why you shouldn't block on async code*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). The reason [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34263526/1870803) works is because using `ConfigureAwait(false)` prevents the synchronization context from following to the continuation, but that is just a dirty workaround which covers up the actual problem of your code.

Instead of doing that, you should also use an async event handler and `await` on your method as well:

```
public async void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await usernameAvailable();
}
```

Side note - Async methods should have the `Async` postfix added to them, so your method should actually be named `UsernameAvaliableAsync()`

Comment: You've done it! I've made my event handler async, added await inside the switch I'm running checks in and it works exactly how it should! I'm not so new to C# but I'm a big noob when it comes to async functions. And thanks for the rename tip. I've changed the name as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to the troubled line fixed the issue and everything works fine now!

old:

```
var response = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

fixed:

```
var response = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Can you confirm that it is related to the dead lock problem described here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html ? If so, please consider linking this blog post or (even better) giving a small explanation in your answer.

Comment: @Abbondanza Yes, I've added the ConfigureAwait(false) from that blog post, however there's no actual explanation I could post. I just tried what it said there and somehow it worked, however, as I'm in a remote desktop session, I later realized it worked like a normal synchronous method. Yuval's answer made the function and it's functionality really asychronous.